# Get upcoming date with strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I would like to get the upcoming date if it has passed when using strtotime.

My code:

```
date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime('1 January'));
```

That returns 2014.01.01 00:00:00. I would like it to return 2015.01.01 00:00:00 as the date has passed. If today would be January 1 it should return 2014.01.01 00:00:00.

`date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime('this friday'));` is working just like that but I would like to somehow be able to work with dates instead of weekdays.

Comment: `echo date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime('1 January' . ( date('z') == 0 ? '' : 'next year')));`

Comment: I do not understand the example you describe - it seems to contradict itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function upcomingDate($target)
{
    $today = mktime(0,0,0);
    $time  = strtotime($target);
    if ($time == $today)
        return $today;
    elseif ($time < $today)
        return strtotime($target . ' next year');
    else
        return $time;
}
```